# Open dialer with tel protocol Chrome link

Tags: google-chrome, hyperlink, telephony, regedit

I would like to open windows `dialer.exe` with tel link on Chrome 
Example link `tel:+123456789` open

Windows dialer with tel number:

[image: windows dialer with tel number]

I tried to edit in the regedit:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\callto]
@="URL:callto"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\tel]
@="URL:tel"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\dialer.callto]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\dialer.callto\Shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\dialer.callto\Shell\Open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\dialer.callto\Shell\Open\Command]
@="dialer %1"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Dialer]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Dialer\Capabilities]
"ApplicationDescription"="Dialer"
"ApplicationName"="Dialer"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Dialer\Capabilities\URLAssociations]
"callto"="dialer.callto"
"tel"="dialer.callto"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications]
"Dialer"="Software\\Dialer\\Capabilities"
```

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/1112229/cant-change-tel-protocol-handler-in-windows-10

We have to change dialer %1 but I do not know by what...
I have to change the default program for tel protocol but I don't see `dialer.exe`

Default program for tel protocol:

[image: default program for tel protocol]

What should I do?